# Functions determined by characters are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, functions

Let $X$ be a set with an action on $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$. For a Dirichlet character $\chi \pmod N$ we set
$$R(\chi)=\left\{ f:X \to \mathbb{C} ~\mid~ f(l s)=\chi(l)f(s) \text{ for all } l\in \mathbb{N} \text{ with } \gcd(l,N)=1,s\in X \right\}.$$
Are these functions $f\in R(\chi)$ linearly independent?

**Edit:** If they are not linearly independent, what is the conditions need to be added to these functions to be linearly independent? My target here is to study these functions and find a basis.

Best regards.

Comment: We don't see many problems about $s\in X$ on this website.

Comment: It is not polite to change your question after it has been answered. Better to accept the answer, if it does answer the question, and then post your new question as a new question, with links pointing both ways between the two questions.

Comment: Dear Gerry Myrson, thanks for your reply. Your answer was helpful. It is not good in my opinion to open a new question. I thought that it is better to edit my post. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is in the set, and $g=2f$. Then $g(ls)=2f(ls)=2\chi(l)f(s)=\chi(l)g(s)$, so $g$ is in the set, but $f$ and $g$ are certainly not linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If it is not linearly independent? what is the conditions need to be added to these functions to be linearly independent? My target here is to study these functions and find a basis.?  many thanks